# reassign default parameter on function call

Tags: c++, assign, function-call, default-parameters

I'm sure this has been asked hundred of times before, but curiously I can't find anything... I wonder how I can reassign a value to a default function parameter upon call specifically, omitting other parameters that stand to the left of it.

This does not compile, as I was used from python. But how to do it?

```
void test(int i=0, int j=1){

    std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;

}

int main()
{

    test(j=2);

}
```

## Edit

Ok, it's not possible. Let me rephrase my question then. WHY is it not possible?

Comment: oh. can you explain why?

Comment: Because they didn't design the language that way.

Comment: This feature does not exist in C++. You just can't do it. I'm not sure what other explanation you're looking for.

Comment: There could have been a technical or philosophical decision behind that. I don't see what advantages it gives not to have that feature. And who downvotes such question?

Comment: "I don't see what advantages it gives not to have that feature."  C++ compilers are already complicated enough.  Once you know enough of the language to make a recommendation on how this proposed feature should interact with other language features such as function templating, then you should make a recommendation to the committee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, your question is *why* it's not allowed rather than if it *is* allowed.  Knowing that you come from Python, the answer is easier to explain.

In Python, an assignment is an *statement*, but not an *expression*. That means that you cannot assign a value to a variable in, for example, a function call:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...  return bar
... 
>>> x=0
>>> foo(x=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Meanwhile, in C++, an assignment is an *expression*, and not an *statement*. Thus, something like this is allowed:

```
void foo(int x) {
    // ...
}

void oof() {
    int x = 0;
    foo(x = 1);
}
```

In this situation, `1` is assigned to `x`, and the new value of `x` is passed on as an argument to `foo()`. All this clutter comes from a man named [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), who for no one's good decided to preserve (some) compatibility with the inventions of another man, namely [Dennis MacAlistair Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie).

Now, it's pretty obvious to understand why allowing keyword parameters in C++ would involve unresolvable stack overflows (but of the compiler, not of your program...). How would the program differentiate between a traditional `assign-and-return` expression as described above, and a keyword parameter? It's simply impossible to do so without modifying the language to the point it's no longer even part of the C family.

This mess is (somewhat) resolved by the fact that Python didn't wanted compatibility with C/C++/C--/~C/!C/*C/&C/..., but it did wanted to allow keyword parameters, and thus another man, namely [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), decided to make assignments statements, as they have always needed to be. This allowed for the syntax used above in C++ to be available in Python for keyword arguments.

Ah! And, if you have any ideas to make C++ even more complex, why not go and say the first thing that comes to your mind to [ISO/ETC JTC1, SC22, WG21](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee)? I'm sure they'll standarize it, whatever it is, and you'll be spyied for the rest of your life by the [some gnomes fabricated in Redmond](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal).

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of explanation I hoped for.